# NSUserDefault Array Is Empty After Reloading iOS (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults, nsdecimalnumber

My objective is to create a budgeting application in Swift that:

1. Saves an array of inputs (numbers).
2. Saves and loads array on reload.

Here's the short version of the code:

```
var adding: [NSDecimalNumber] = []

func clickAction {
let addingAmount = NSDecimalNumber(string: textInput.text)
adding.append(addingAmount) }

defaults.setObject(adding, forKey: "addingArray")
```

And in viewDidLoad:

```
if let addingIsNotNil = defaults.arrayForKey("addingArray") as [AnyObject]! {
        var adding = defaults.arrayForKey("addingArray") as [AnyObject]!
    }
```

**To explain:**

I created an NSDecimalNumber array to collect the inputs:

On clickAction, an input will be appended to the array and the updated array will be assigned to an NSUserDefault. (At this point a println of the default will display the entire array correctly.)

The problem is that if I reload, the same println is now empty! I'm assuming that the default is definitely being saved on exit, but turns up empty on reload because of the first variable.

```
var adding: [NSDecimalNumber] = []
```

Does anyone know a way around this? It seems that after reloading, everything will point to the empty adding array (which i need to store the numbers). I tried creating other variables inside of the clickAction using if else to no avail.

Comment: First order of affairs I suggest is to make a call `NSUserDefaults.synchronize()` right after you add the array into NSUserDefaults.

Without it, NSUserDefaults saves the defaults at random times, and if you quit the app before it does that automatically, it will not save the data.

Comment: Definitely! I didn't list this in the question but I synchronize every default after setting (though I read not to synchronize post iOS8) . Any other insights? http://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/